Change spacing between letters in math mode
$abcd$

gives

I want $a\,b\,c\,d$

But I want it for all my math equations. What setting do I have to change? What value affects this spacing?
I tried
\thinmuskip
\medmuskip
\thickmuskip

but none affects the spacing I want to change.

I think you'll just have to manually space it each time.

There is no setting that can do what you want. How many books have you seen that use this style?

, for spacing was just an example, but I'd like to slighly increase the spacing. Sometime, especially when I use \mathcal and regular characters next to each other, spacing looks is too tight. I can do it manually for those few cases, but I was wondering if it was possible to set it for all the document. No big deal.

Very similar question: Default spaces between letters in math-mode

@EmanueleNardi Great thanks! Somehow I didn't find it with Google and it wasn't recommended when I wrote mine... I'll close this.
